# Issue with ++ operator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax, logic, operators

I'm attempting to add 1 to the variable levelname everytime the LevelChange function is called. However, everytime its called it resets the value to 1 like its originally set in the beginning of the code. I'm used to c++ and very confused. This code is a bit sloppy because ive tried a ton of ways to solve this. Any help would be appreciated. 
Theres a bracket missing because for some reason i cant get this line to go in the code block.

```
public class NextLevel : MonoBehaviour {
    int levelname = 1;
    int newlevelname;
    string levelnameS;

   void LevelChange()
   {
       levelname++; 
       newlevelname = levelname;
       string levelnameS = newlevelname.ToString(); //Converts newlevelname which is an int value to a string
       Debug.Log(levelnameS); //prints to the console

       SceneManager.LoadScene(levelnameS); //changes scene based on the level name. In this case its a number because thats what the levels are named.
       Debug.Log(levelname);       
   }

   void Update()
   {       
       if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
       {            
           LevelChange(); //calls the level change function                  
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Where do you keep the instance of this class?

Comment: @VisualVincent its a component of the event handler object. it functions when it comes to switching from one level to another but then the value wont go up more than once. Does that answer your question? im not positive what youre asking.

Comment: Then your problem is likely that a new instance is created every time you go to a new level. Take the others' advice and make the variable `static`.

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks man!

Comment: No problem. You can read more about `static` on the [**MSDN Documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use  `public static int levelname = 1;`
instead of `int levelname=1`

Comment: instead of thanks upvote the answer this will help other

Comment: as a general rule you really should NOT use statics, or globals, in engineering software.  as time goes on try to build your basic software engineering skills!

Answer (score 4):

`levelname` is  a instance property. Each instance of class `NextLevel` has own value of this. So if you every time create new instance of `NextLevel` and call `Update` count always start from 1.

You can switch `levelname` to static property or always use one instance of class `NextLevel`.

Comment: i solved the problem but just for the future, how would i go about only using one instance of NextLevel?

Comment: @user3103529 I don't know how you create and use a object type `NextLevel`, too few example code. But read about [diferences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629(v=vs.71).aspx) between static and instance members, use static members have some consequeces eg. if you want more than one instance of class static members always has the same value for each instance..